# List specific data with lambda via MVC controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, lambda

I'm trying to list every comments created by the the specific user (Users Id stored in `Session["LoggedUserID"]`) but I'm having hard time solving the lambda expression as I basically never done it before.

The following code is faulty, but this about what I had in mind.

```
 public ActionResult MyComments(Guid? id)
        {
            id = new Guid(Session["LoggedUserID"].ToString());

            var comments = db.Comments.Include(m=> m.CreatorUserId.Equals(id));

            return View(comments.ToList());

        }
```

*Addintional info:*

- *Database-first*
- *Using Guids for Id's.*

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: You are using `Include` instead of `Where`, include should be used when you want to expand an entity inside your comments, ex: the user CreatorUser

Answer (score 2):

It will be more helpful if you would publish your relevant entities SQL scheme, but this should suffice.

1. I've used LINQ to Entities `.Where` method in order to filter only the one matching the given id.
2. Include is not needed, because it is used for loading relative entities, which is not needed for **Comments** table.

**Code:**

```
public ActionResult MyComments(Guid? id)
{
    id = Guid.Parse(Session["LoggedUserID"].ToString());

    var review = db.Comments.Where(m => m.CreatorUserId.Equals(id));
    var result = review.ToList(); 

    return View(result);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this instead of `include`,

```
db.Comments.Where(m=> m.CreatorUserId == id);
```

Hope helps,